Vaadin dialog gets resize when dragged
I am facing one issue that whenever I dragged the dialog, the dialog gets sinked initially then it working fine.
code
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setDraggable(true);
dialog.setResizable(true);
dialog.open();

The code is written in vaadin
vaadin-version : 23.3.6
spring-boot-version: 2.7.5
java-version: 11
How to solve this issue?

I can't reproduce the issue. You should create a  Minimal Reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Can't reproduce either - both Chrome and Firefox behave as expected. Please provide more code/context.
